# How do I make expanded fonts and install them?

Tags: pdftex, dvi, font-expansion, font-map

I am running `pdfTeX` with `dvi` output. If font expansion is enabled, then I need the extra fonts, such as `cmr10+20`. When I try to view the dvi, xdvi tries to make various fonts and fails; the file `missfont.log` gets appended various commands, such as `mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 cmr10+20`. If I try that command, I get an error, with `mktexpk: perhaps cmr10+20 is missing from the map file.` It seems first I have to modify the map file. I don't know whether that is all I have to do or not, but I don't know how to do that for a font that does not exist yet.
I realize that if I used pdf output, this would not be needed. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

**Edit:** In response to a request, here is a sample file. The problem will occur with any file that needs font expansion, however.

```
\pdfoutput=0
\pdffontexpand\tenrm 20 20 10 autoexpand
\pdfadjustspacing=2
\hsize=3in
There is a striking, but easily established, correspondence between
electrical networks and
random walks on graphs (or on networks). 

\bye
```

**Edit 2:**
The fonts I am actually using most and thus would like to enable expansion for are `ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1` and `ntx-Italic-tlf-ot1`. I would also like to enable expansion for `ntxmi`.

Comment: I think that `autoexpand` only works for PDF output and that for DVI output you need to prepare in advance the TFM files for the expanded fonts.

Comment: Exactly. My question is how to do that.

Comment: My question is *why do you want to do that?* `;-)`

Comment: Because it seems easier than to convert all my macros for my book to work with pdf output, as well as convert 100 figures from eps to pdf and make sure everything works at the end. Besides, this is the usual result with dvi output for pdfTeX, yet I could find nowhere that says what to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `autoexpand` option only works for PDF output, whereas for DVI output you have to create the expanded font instances in advance. Assuming you want to use the original Computer Modern Roman MetaFont, you would have to:

- create a copy of the font source (let's say `cmr10.mf`),
- add a line after the place where the unit width is defined:

```
   u#:=20/36pt#;      % unit width
   u#:=u#+20/1000u#;  % <-- scale by 20
```

- rename the amended file to `cmr10+20.mf`.
- Repeat the above steps for as many instances as you like (e.g., `-20`, `-15`, `-10`, `-5`, `+5`, `+10`, `+15`).
- Repeat the above steps for all fonts that you want to have expanded (e.g., `cmr12.mf`, `cmti10.mf` ...).

When running `pdftex` the corresponding `tfm` and `pk` files will then be created. (BTW: You should remove the `autoexpand` keyword for `\pdffontexpand`, so as not to confuse `pdftex`.)

For Type1 fonts and Multiple Master fonts, the procedures are different. You can find all the details in Hàn Thé Thành's [thesis](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb21-4/tb69thanh.pdf), p. 370.

---

**EDIT** Since you are actually not using CMR, but a Type1 font, you'd have to create the expanded `tfm` files in advance:

- `` grep ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1 `kpsewhich newtx.map` `` tells us that the font is a reencoded Type1 font:

  ```
  ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1 TeXGyreTermes-Regular " encntx-ot1-tlf ReEncodeFont " <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <qtmr.pfb
  ```
- the base `afm` file is `ntxtmr.afm` (in `fonts/afm/public/newtx/`). (The base file for italics would be `ntxtmri.afm`, for bold `ntxtmb.afm`, and for bold italics `ntxtmbi.afm`.)
- you can create the expanded `tfm`s with `afm2tfm`:

  ```
  afm2tfm ntxtmr.afm -e 1.020 -T ntx-ot1-tlf.enc ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1+20.tfm
  afm2tfm ntxtmr.afm -e 0.980 -T ntx-ot1-tlf.enc ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1-20.tfm
  ```

  and so on for all required steps.
- finally, you have to add the new `map` entries, based on the original one in `newtx.map`, adding the `ExtendFont` part (let's write them into a new file `newtx-ext.map`):

  ```
  ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1+20 TeXGyreTermes-Regular " 1.020 ExtendFont encntx-ot1-tlf ReEncodeFont " <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <qtmr.pfb
  ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1-20 TeXGyreTermes-Regular " 0.980 ExtendFont encntx-ot1-tlf ReEncodeFont " <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <qtmr.pfb
  ```

  You can then enable this map file with:

  ```
  updmap-sys --enable Map=newtx-ext.map
  ```
- Repeat for all steps, and for all fonts.

Comment: In fact, my main font is ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1, not cmr. I see only a tfm file. I don't know what type of font it is and without any other files, I don't know how to modify it in any of the 3 ways you mention.

Comment: @RussLyons See `newtx.map` for details. Type1 reencoded. The map  file will let you identify the type1 fonts you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I just noticed it, having spent the last 3 hours learning about `fontinst` and attempting to learn about `\latinfamily` (about which `fontinst` says: "There is really much too much about this command for it to be described in full here. Please see other available documentation."--but where is that other doc?). Since I am doing so little, your method looks much better. However, I have to figure out how to add `map` entries. I presume I need a new file.

Comment: P.S. Probably `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation` will tell me.

Comment: Robert: Sorry, I still am confused. First, how did you decide on `ntxtmr.afm`? I would have thought it was `qtmr.afm`. Second, there seem to be many map files for various interpreters; what map files should I modify or create? I think you are saying I only need to worry about psfonts.map. Third, do I need either of `udpmap-sys` or `texhash`? I think so, but I'm not sure how they work.

Comment: @RussLyons For the `afm` file I simply looked into the directory `fonts/afm/public/newtx/`, because the font you use is part of the `newtx` package. With regards to installing  your new `newtx-ext.map`, this is really not different from enabling any other map file, as detailed in the question you linked to: put the file in a place where it will be found, update the data base, and enable the map file with `updmap(-sys)`.

Comment: @Robert Thanks. Now `pdftex` runs fine, but xdvi complains and I cannot create the pdf from the dvi. The errors are `kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+32/600 --dpi 632 ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1-20`, `mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1-20.`, and `mktexpk: perhaps ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1-20 is missing from the map file.`.

Comment: @RussLyons Sorry, I have no idea about `xdvi`. Does another `texhash` help? Does `dvips` run fine?

Comment: @Robert I did `texhash` multiple times, alternating with `udpmap`. `dvips` has the same problem. I tried `sudo -H mktexlsr`, but that did not help.

Comment: @RussLyons What does `kpsewhich newtx-ext.map` yield? And what `kpsewhich ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1+20.tfm`? And what happens if you run `dvips -u+newtx-ext.map`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33609/discussion-between-russ-lyons-and-robert).

Comment: @RussLyons Maybe you should edit your question detailing what you did and what still doesn't work. Or even ask a new question, as installing the `map` file is not really related to font expansion but is a "normal" installation problem.

Comment: @Robert Are you sure that `ntxtmr` should appear in the map file just before `TeXGyreTermes-Regular`? At least, not both should appear. I think this does not comport with the format and leads to an error when running dvipdfmx as follows: `dvipdfmx:warning: Invalid char in fontmap line: T
dvipdfmx:warning: Invalid map record in fontmap line 16520 from pdftex.map.
dvipdfmx:warning: -- Ignore the current input buffer: ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1+20 ntxtmr TeXGyreTermes-Regular " 1.020 ExtendFont encntx-ot1-tlf ReEncodeFont " <ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <qtmr.pfb`

Comment: @Robert For `ntx-Italic-tlf-ot1`, I presume I want `ntxtmri.afm`. For `ntxmi`, I presume I cannot use an `afm` file, but instead want `rntxmi.pfb`. If so, why shouldn't I have used `qtrm(i).pfb` for the others? But how do I convert `pfb` to `tfm`?

Comment: @RussLyons Firstly, sorry, the `map` entries were indeed wrong, my bad. Secondly, you can convert a `pfb` to `afm` with `pf2afm` (from `ghostscript`)

Comment: @Robert OK, thanks. Also, I realized that (I think) for `ntxmi`, I want `rtxmi.afm`.

Comment: If you do that you will lose all kerning information as this is found only in the AFM file - not the PFB file. You don't turn PFB files into TFM. You always use AFM. The metrics are in the AFM. Only the little pictures are in the PFB.

Comment: I was wrong about using `rtxmi.afm`. In fact, there appears not to be any `afm` associated to `ntxmi`, but, rather, `ntxmi.vf`. This `vf` is explained here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151872/convert-certain-newtx-fonts-to-truetype-or-opentype I can convert `vf` to `pl` and `pl` to `tfm`, but how would I do font expansion?

Comment: @RussLyons Sorry, but this is really getting too confusing now. Could you not update your question, saying which fonts you are using and which you would like to have expanded? (`ntxmi` is a math font. And as it is virtual font, you'd have to use `fontinst`, for which you would need the source.)

Comment: @Robert Sorry for the confusion. I will limit myself to the `ntx` fonts listed in your edited answer. I'd like to include `ntxmi`, but if that is too hard, I can omit it. What do you mean by "for which you would need the source": do you mean the source for `fontinst`? If I use `fontinst` and use `\latinfamily`, is there documentation of that command?

Comment: @RussLyons Yes, I was referring to the `fontinst` source file (which is not included in the `newtx` package). It _might_ be possible to reverse-engineer this virtual font, ie. to reconstruct the series of `fontinst` commands, but that's not something I would advise to do (`\xscalefont` would be the relevant command to add for expansion). As for documentation, there's `fontinst.pdf`, `fisource.pdf`, and also the `fontinstallationguide.pdf`. `\latinfamily` is only meant to install (Latin) text fonts, not math fonts, so it wouldn't be of any help in the case of `ntxmi`.

Comment: @Robert I don't know what the source file is for `fontinst`, but that's OK. I'm not going to delve into it. None of the docs you mention document `\latinfamily`; however, since you say that's not useful here, I'll forget it. In any case, it seems too hard to deal with virtual fonts, so I'll forget about enabling expansion for `ntxmi`.

Comment: I have posted a new question for installing the fonts here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286838/how-can-i-install-newly-created-fonts

Comment: What does `<ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc` do? I mean the doubling here. Why not just `<[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc`?

Comment: @Robert Does "doubling" have any effect? The two phrases are slightly different, as one has a `[` and one does not. I do not see any difference in output if I change the map file (and I still have the problem of distortions when the expanded font is not the only font for output produced via dvipdfmx).

Comment: @Robert I tested your instructions for cmr. They work, except that the output pdf has lighter glyphs for the expanded fonts; the dvi is the same color for both, while dvips gives lighter color for the *unexpanded* glyphs (same with dvipdf or ps2pdf). What's going on?

Comment: I added detail to the cmr problem here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/287337/58928