# How can I install newly created fonts?

Tags: pdftex, texlive, dvi, dvipdfmx, installing-fonts

I am using `texlive2015` on Ubuntu 14.04. The distro is owned by `root` and I have to use `sudo` for such things as `updmap`. [I have another computer where I changed ownership to me, but the following problems are similar there.] I am using `pdftex` with `dvi` output, which I then convert to `pdf` via `dvipdfmx`. (This is for historical reasons: I started work on this 700-page book 20 years ago. It is (e)plain `tex` with lots of my own macros and 100 `eps` figures.) I now want to enable font expansion (this is the reason for using `pdftex`, besides character protrusion.) However, I cannot reliably get the new fonts to work, especially if I use more than one font. Here is a simple example.

```
\pdfoutput=0 
\font\tenrm=ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1
\font\tenit=ntx-Italic-tlf-ot1
\hsize=5truein
\tenrm

\pdffontexpand\tenrm 20 20 5
\pdffontexpand\tenit 20 20 5
\pdfadjustspacing=2

Our {\it major topics} include random walks and their intimate connection to
electrical networks; uniform spanning trees, their limiting forests, and
their marvelous relationships with random walks and electrical networks;
branching processes; percolation and the powerful, elegant mass-transport
technique; isoperimetric inequalities and how they relate to both random
walks and percolation; minimal spanning trees and forests, and their
connections to percolation; Hausdorff dimension, capacity, and how to
understand them via trees; and random walks on Galton-Watson trees.
Connections among our topics are pervasive and rich, making for surprising
and enjoyable proofs.

\bye
```

I followed the instructions at [How do I make expanded fonts and install them?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285009/how-do-i-make-expanded-fonts-and-install-them), but they did not ever work fully. I have the above file in the same directory as the map file and the new fonts. I cannot get `xdvi` to work properly, even with only the roman fonts here. The error includes

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1+15
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1+15.
mktexpk: perhaps ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1+15 is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
```

`dvipdfmx` is similar:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600
ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1+10
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1+10.
mktexpk: perhaps ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1+10 is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

dvipdfmx:warning: Could not locate a virtual/physical font for TFM
"ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1+10".
dvipdfmx:warning: >> There are no valid font mapping entry for this font.
dvipdfmx:warning: >> Font file name "ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1+10" was assumed
but failed to locate that font.
dvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without .vf or "physical" font for PDF
output...

Output file removed.
```

If I run `dvipdfmx -f newtx-ext.map`, then I will get output. However, the italics cause distortions in spacing and scaling (more evident in a longer file, especially with `ntxmi` math font unexpanded mixed in):

[image: pdf output]

Similarly, if I use only italics, the `pdf` is fine, but if I mix `rm`, then I will get similar distortions. In addition, if I expand only `\tenrm`, not `\tenit`, then the results are similarly poor. `dvips` fails to find the correct fonts, but `dvips -u+newtx-ext.map` produces perfect output:

[image: dvips output]

However, I need a suitable dvi file in order to use `dvipdfmx` (for a proper pdf file with my book, not with this test file).

`kpsewhich ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1+20.tfm` reports `./ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1+20.tfm`, `kpsewhich ntx-Italic-tlf-ot1+20.tfm` reports `./ntx-Italic-tlf-ot1+20.tfm` and `kpsewhich newtx-ext.map` reports `./newtx-ext.map`.

Here is the map file:

```
ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1+20 TeXGyreTermes-Regular " 1.020 ExtendFont encntx-ot1-tlf ReEncodeFont " <ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <qtmr.pfb
ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1+15 TeXGyreTermes-Regular " 1.015 ExtendFont encntx-ot1-tlf ReEncodeFont " <ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <qtmr.pfb
ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1+10 TeXGyreTermes-Regular " 1.010 ExtendFont encntx-ot1-tlf ReEncodeFont " <ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <qtmr.pfb
ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1+5 TeXGyreTermes-Regular " 1.005 ExtendFont encntx-ot1-tlf ReEncodeFont " <ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <qtmr.pfb
ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1-20 TeXGyreTermes-Regular " 0.980 ExtendFont encntx-ot1-tlf ReEncodeFont " <ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <qtmr.pfb
ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1-15 TeXGyreTermes-Regular " 0.985 ExtendFont encntx-ot1-tlf ReEncodeFont " <ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <qtmr.pfb
ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1-10 TeXGyreTermes-Regular " 0.990 ExtendFont encntx-ot1-tlf ReEncodeFont " <ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <qtmr.pfb
ntx-Regular-tlf-ot1-5 TeXGyreTermes-Regular " 0.995 ExtendFont encntx-ot1-tlf ReEncodeFont " <ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <qtmr.pfb
ntx-Italic-tlf-ot1+20 TeXGyreTermes-Italic " 1.020 ExtendFont encntx-ot1-tlf ReEncodeFont " <ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <qtmri.pfb
ntx-Italic-tlf-ot1+15 TeXGyreTermes-Italic " 1.015 ExtendFont encntx-ot1-tlf ReEncodeFont " <ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <qtmri.pfb
ntx-Italic-tlf-ot1+10 TeXGyreTermes-Italic " 1.010 ExtendFont encntx-ot1-tlf ReEncodeFont " <ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <qtmri.pfb
ntx-Italic-tlf-ot1+5 TeXGyreTermes-Italic " 1.005 ExtendFont encntx-ot1-tlf ReEncodeFont " <ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <qtmri.pfb
ntx-Italic-tlf-ot1-20 TeXGyreTermes-Italic " 0.980 ExtendFont encntx-ot1-tlf ReEncodeFont " <ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <qtmri.pfb
ntx-Italic-tlf-ot1-15 TeXGyreTermes-Italic " 0.985 ExtendFont encntx-ot1-tlf ReEncodeFont " <ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <qtmri.pfb
ntx-Italic-tlf-ot1-10 TeXGyreTermes-Italic " 0.990 ExtendFont encntx-ot1-tlf ReEncodeFont " <ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <qtmri.pfb
ntx-Italic-tlf-ot1-5 TeXGyreTermes-Italic " 0.995 ExtendFont encntx-ot1-tlf ReEncodeFont " <ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <qtmri.pfb
```

This map file is incorporated properly (I believe) in both `/root/.texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex_dl14.map` and `/root/.texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/psfonts_t1.map`.

The output of `sudo -H updmap --force --enable Map=newtx-ext.map` is

```
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /root/.texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg file for writing changes:
  /root/.texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
dvips output dir: "/root/.texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
pdftex output dir: "/root/.texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfmx output dir: "/root/.texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"

updmap is creating new map files
using the following configuration:
  LW35 font names                  : URWkb (default)
  prefer outlines                  : true (default)
  texhash enabled                  : true
  download standard fonts (dvips)  : true (default)
  download standard fonts (pdftex) : true (default)
  kanjiEmbed replacement string    : noEmbed (default)
  kanjiVariant replacement string  :  (default)
  create a mapfile for pxdvi       : false (default)

Scanning for LW35 support files  [  3 files]
Scanning for MixedMap entries    [ 49 files]
Scanning for KanjiMap entries    [  6 files]
Scanning for Map entries         [209 files]

Generating output for dvipdfmx...
Generating output for ps2pk...
Generating output for dvips...
Generating output for pdftex...

Files generated:
  /root/.texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap:
       15762 2016-01-09 15:56:43 builtin35.map
       21235 2016-01-09 15:56:43 download35.map
     1093081 2016-01-09 15:56:43 psfonts_pk.map
     1353946 2016-01-09 15:56:43 psfonts_t1.map
     1348439 2016-01-09 15:56:43 ps2pk.map
          14 2016-01-09 15:56:44 psfonts.map -> psfonts_t1.map
  /root/.texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap:
     1348446 2016-01-09 15:56:44 pdftex_dl14.map
     1346781 2016-01-09 15:56:44 pdftex_ndl14.map
          15 2016-01-09 15:56:44 pdftex.map -> pdftex_dl14.map
  /root/.texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap:
        6109 2016-01-09 15:56:43 kanjix.map

Transcript written on "/root/.texmf-var/web2c/updmap.log".
updmap: Updating ls-R files.
```

I really hope someone can help me. I have spent many frustrating hours over the last month on this, but I can see that if I get it to work, it will be worthwhile. Thank you!

**Edit:**

After cleaning the results of `update` (without `-sys`), I ran `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=newtx-ext.map`; that did very little, so I ran `sudo updmap-sys --force --enable Map=newtx-ext.map`. It gave the same results as above, with the following exceptions: The first line was `updmap: resetting $HOME value (was /home/rdlyons) to root's actual home (/root).` and the end was

```
WARNING: updmap has found mismatched files!

The following files have been generated as listed above,
but will not be found because overriding files exist, listed below.
 builtin35.map: /root/.texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/builtin35.map
 download35.map: /root/.texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/download35.map
 kanjix.map: /root/.texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap/kanjix.map
 pdftex.map: /root/.texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
 pdftex_dl14.map: /root/.texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex_dl14.map
 pdftex_ndl14.map: /root/.texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex_ndl14.map
 ps2pk.map: /root/.texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/ps2pk.map
 psfonts.map: /root/.texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/psfonts.map
 psfonts_pk.map: /root/.texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/psfonts_pk.map
 psfonts_t1.map: /root/.texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/psfonts_t1.map
(Run updmap --help for full documentation of updmap.)

Transcript written on "/var/lib/texmf/web2c/updmap.log".
updmap: Updating ls-R files.
```

So I moved that directory `/root/.texmf-var/fonts/map` and then that last problem disappeared. However, nothing was fixed: the exact same problems occur.

Comment: Please read [this question and answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255709/why-shouldnt-i-use-getnonfreefonts-to-install-additional-fonts-why-shouldnt-i) which I wrote to explain why you should never use `updmap`. You should clean up the results of using it thoroughly, especially if you have run it as the user you normally use to compile documents with (presumably not root) or without changing that user's environment. The stuff in root's home shouldn't hurt anything so just leave that if you aren't confident cleaning it.

Comment: If you have all of the files in your working directory try `\pdfmapfile{+<filename>.map}` but I'm not sure if this works in DVI mode. Note that the files which include the map file fragment, as shown in your output, are never read when you compile documents. (Unless you compile as root which would be an extremely bad idea.)

Comment: @cfr No, it does not work in `dvi` mode: `pdfTeX error (\pdfmapfile): not allowed in DVI mode`. I will try your other suggestion.

Comment: @cfr The second command you suggest, `mv -n $(dirname $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME)) $(dirname $(kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME)).bkup`, gives an error: `mv: cannot move ‘/home/rdlyons’ to ‘/home/rdlyons.bkup’: Permission denied`. BTW, I normally use `tsch`, but had to use `bash` (with which I am not familiar) for your syntax. (The result of `kpsewhich -var TEXMFHOME` is `/home/rdlyons/texmf`.)

Comment: @cfr I moved the directories. There was no change in behavior. I ran `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=newtx-ext.map`. Again, no change in behavior. This is what I expected, since earlier I only ran `updmap` after finding that I could not get satisfactory results with `updmap-sys`.

Comment: You need to move or rename probably `~/.texlive2015` if you have ever run `updmap` as yourself. You certainly shouldn't move `~`. Thanks for reporting the error with the code. I've corrected the answer. Note that the commands there will only clean up the mess. They will not enable the fonts.  For that, if there's no DVI equivalent of adding the map file, the best option is to install the fonts into TEXMFLOCAL, run `mktexlsr` and then edit the config file and run `updmap-sys`. This is straightforward with upstream's TeX Live. With a distro's packaging, you need to work with their config.

Comment: @cfr I don't have any such directory as `~/.texlive2015`.

Comment: Then it shouldn't cause you any problems. Do you know what `<ntx-ot1-tlf.enc <[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc` is supposed to do? Why the doubling rather than just `<[ntx-ot1-tlf.enc`?

Comment: @cfr Are you suggesting to install the `tfm` files into `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/tfm/local/`, which is currently empty? Should I also install something in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1/local` (also empty)? I don't know what you mean by "upstream", but I installed this myself, not using a distro package manager. BTW, I still have `texlive2013`; is that a problem?

Comment: @cfr No, I do not understand the doubling. I just followed the instructions on the site given in my post.

Comment: Your installation of TeX Live is your distro's, though. You didn't install with upstream's installer ('vanilla' TeX Live). So you should check where TEXMFLOCAL is using `kpsewhich -var TEXMFLOCAL`. I don't know if it uses the same locations or not, though the `local` at the end looks odd. (I've seen it before, but don't know what it is for.) You don't need to install the type1 fonts as you've got those already, but the map file and the TFM files. (And anything else crucial you made.) I'd use e.g. `TEXMFLOCAL/fonts/tfm/public/newtx-ext/` for the TFMs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34084/discussion-between-russ-lyons-and-cfr).